# OS X 10.11 / Xcode 7.0.1 git push fails silently

Tags: xcode, git

After upgrading to OS X 10.11 and Xcode 7.0.1, git push fails when invoked from Xcode's Source Control menu. It fails silently, with a happy message "Push Successful".

When I execute "git push" from the command line, the push succeeds.

I'm pretty sure my origin is set correctly inside Xcode, because Source Control -> Pull works fine.

My local store is called "master" and my remote store is called "origin". I have no branches.

"origin" resides on my other mac, accessed via OS X File Sharing, referenced with the URL "file:///Volumes/git-repositories/%252010.5//" where  is my project name. Unfortunately, I have a space in the URL, which is doubly-encoded by Xcode as %25%20. A clue? But why would Pull work?

The mac hosting "origin" is also running OS X 10.11 / Xcode 7.0.1.  It contains a local "master" and is configured to push to "origin", which exists on the same disk.  It fails in EXACTLY the same manner: Xcode Push silently fails, while Xcode Pull and command-line push succeeds.

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: ""origin" resides on my other mac, accessed via OS X File Sharing, referenced with the URL "file:///Volumes/git-repositories/%252010.5//" where is my project name." That is legal, but the way I would (and do) accomplish this is to open a free private Bitbucket repo and use that as an intermediary for pushing and pulling from both machines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but legal constraints prevent me from using an offsite repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:** I created a new origin that has no spaces in its path.

Speculation: this is a bug in Xcode 7.0.1's git repo handling, when escaping URL's.