# Facing issue while pushing changes from XCode 7.x / 8.x to TFS - Git repository

Tags: xcode, git, tfs

After Xcode has update to version 7.x / 8.x, I have a problem of pushing the changes from the local GIT to  the remote TFS - GIT repository.

While pushing, I am getting the waring that The push operation failed because no matching remote could be found. Make sure there's a remote entry in your Git configuration for the remote URL 'https://abc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/Project%20IOS/_git/Project-IOS'.

But, I am able to pull the changes from the same remote TFS - GIT repository

Unlike Xcode 7.x / 8.x,  I am able to push the changes from Xcode 6.x and also able to push using Terminal.

Can somebody help me how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you be able to push with command line? Did this error only occurs with GUI?

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the blankspace "%20" in the repository URL. There seems to be some issue with XCode 7/8 that it cannot handle the white space in the repository URL. If you push to a remote URL without blankspace in it, it can push successfully. I didn't find any solution for this issue either. As a workaround, I push the changes from terminal via Git push command.

You can also find the same issue here: [OS X 10.11 / Xcode 7.0.1 git push fails silently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855274/os-x-10-11-xcode-7-0-1-git-push-fails-silently).

Comment: After removing the blankspace in remove URL, I can push the changes successfully. @Edd

Comment: @ManojSengottuvel Can you mark it as answer if it helps you? :)